# Refresh plot after mouse click event

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, bar-chart

I need to refresh a matplotlib bar plot after a mouse click. The plot should take the event.ydata value and replot data according to it. I was able to retrieve this value from the mouse event, but when I try to refresh the plot nothing seems to happen. Here is my code:

```
#df is a pd.DataFrame, I have to plot just the df_mean with error bars (marginOfError)
df_mean = df.mean(axis=1)
df_std = df.std(axis=1)
marginOfError = 1.96*df_std/np.sqrt(3650)

index = np.arange(4)

def print_data(threshold):    
    colors = []

    for i,err in zip(df_mean,marginOfError):
        if(i + err < threshold):
            colors.append('#001f7c')
        elif(i - err > threshold):
            colors.append('#bc0917')
        else:
            colors.append('#e0d5d6')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    plt.bar(index, df_mean, 0.85,
                     alpha=0.85,
                     color=colors,
                     yerr=marginOfError)

    plt.xticks(index, df.index)

    #horizontal threshold line
    ax.plot([-0.5, 3.5], [threshold, threshold], "c-")

# first print data with a given threshold value
print_data(df_mean.iloc[1])

def onclick(event):
    plt.gca().set_title('{}'.format(event.ydata))
    print_data(event.ydata)    

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would probably want to plot each new plot in the same figure. Therefore you should create the figure and axes outside the repetitively called function. Thus put `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` outside the function, and inside you may clear the axes, `ax.clear()` before drawing a new plot to it.

At the end, you need to actually redraw the canvas by putting

```
plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()
```

at the end of the `onclick` function.