# Refresh text after click and manipulate data plotly dash

Tags: python, plotly, interactive, plotly-dash

I am new to Plotly Dash (Python). My question might be wrongly asked or naive, so please guide me in the right dirction if thats the case.

In my IDE, I have a dataframe `library` with a few hundred short texts. What I would like to do is to create an interface in which users see one piece of text per time and submit an (binary) input for this text (this needs to be saved in a new column/dataframe). Then, after they have given the input, a new short text will show for which they are asked to give their binary input again. These steps continue until all texts have been read.

Since I am new to Plotly, Dash, I don't know:

- if this is possible
- what type of functions I need to look for
- how to write the code for this

So far, I have only found how to write a large piece of text:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

for text in library:
     markdown_text = text    
     app.layout = html.Div([
         dcc.Markdown(children=markdown_text)
     ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So any answer that gets me closer to implementation is welcome.

Ps. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963128/refresh-plot-after-mouse-click-event) answer is specifically focused on plots, so therefore not relevant to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have `library` which has your initial texts to display and a user input.
Include an `@app.callback` with the user input value. Then the function for the callback can call the relevant text again from library and display in the `div` area of the layout.

Remember, you need to have `id` for all the elements on your page, so that callbacks can work correctly. Do refer to the examples given in dash documentation for [callbacks](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2).